# How to organize code with __init__.py?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, organization

I am just starting off using google app engine, and have been looking around for good practices and code organization. Most of my problems lie from confusion of `__init__.py`.

My current test structure looks like

```
/website
  main.py
  /pages
    __init__.py #1
    blog.py
    hello2.py
    hello.py
    /sub
      __init__.py #2
      base.py
```

I am trying to use main.py as a file that simply points to everything in /pages and /pages/sub. Most modules in /pages share almost all the same imports (ex. import urllib), is there a way to define that everything in /pages imports what I want rather than adding it in every individual module?

Currently in `__init__.py` #1 I have

```
from sub.base import *
```

Yet my module blog.py says BaseHandler (a function in base.py) not defined.
My end goal is to have something like ...

```
main.py
from pages import *
#be able to call any function in /pages without having to do blog.func1() or hello.func2()
#rather just func1() and func2()
```

And to be able to share common imports for modules in `/pages` in `__init__.py`. So that they share for example urllib and all functions from base.py. Thank you for taking the time to read this post, I look forward to your insight.

Comment: Items imported into `__init__` are not automatically also available to modules in the same package. You'll still need to explicitely import `BaseHandler` where needed, such as in blog.py.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you think `__init__.py` is an initializer for the other modules in the package. It is not. It turns `pages` into a package (allowing its files and subdirectories to be modules), and it is executed, like a normal module would be, when your program calls `import pages`. Imagine that it's named `pages.py` instead.

So if you really want to dump everything into the same namespace, init #2 can contain  `from base import *` (which will import everything in `base` to the namespace of `sub`), and `blog.py` can contain `from sub import *`. Got it?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the purpose of __init__.py , and kudos for the example! Helps a lot, I am now getting the functionality I wanted. I have to play around with it more to really wrap my head around it but you put me in the right direction.